# Is there a way to display the name of a website in uppercase in Google search results?

Tags: seo

I am creating a website and I'm wondering if there is a way to display the name of a website in uppercase in Google search results.

Comment: I'd say it's possible - there are some search results that are at least uppercase in part. However, you are not necessarily in control of exactly what Google uses in the SERPs - so regardless of what you include in the `title` tag, you may not get the same in the SERPs. (Google needs to protect against abuse and all uppercase titles could appear as quite "abusive".)

Comment: NASA has their name all uppercase in the search results.  Not sure if there is anything special they have to do to get that though. https://www.google.com/search?q=nasa

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample given in the comments of NASA the way this appears to have been achieved is by using an `og:site_name` meta tag and a site name in their structured data for all the pages. The thing to remember here though is that Google ranks NASA as a high value and dependable site which is very unlikely to be playing the system with their markup and as such trusts what they put down. While you can use opengraph meta data and structured markup data whether Google will use this or not depends on how Google's ranking algorithms assess your site.

Comment: It is also that NASA would be in an ontology of brand or organization names and associated with the domain name. Other ontologies created by sites such as Wikipedia can also be used. NASA, being well known and long standing, would have their name presented properly as uppercase just like any mixed case name found in an ontology used.